# Can serialNumber of hardware attestation certificate be used to uniquely identify a device?

Tags: certificates

When performing [hardware attestation on Android](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-key-attestation), a new key-pair is created in the TEE, and the whole certificate chain is returned to the user, verifying that the key-pair was indeed created in the TEE.

Non-privileged apps on android can't force TEE to return Serial, MEID and IMEI in the key-pair certificate extension. At least, if they don't have READ_PHONE_STATE permission (but if they do, they can read it using android API anyway).

At least on [Google Pixel](https://gist.github.com/thestinger/27e38cb7939c35cd03d9fff4ac022775) and Samsung devices the chain consists of:

- Generated key-pair certificate. It is unique for each key pair, that is, for each attestation request.
- I suppose, device certificate. Unique for each device.
- I suppose, manufacturer certificate. But on my devices (3 Samsung phones, the model of 2 of them is the same), it also was unique for each device.
- [One of four Google Root certificates](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-key-attestation#root_certificate)

Unlike the key-pair certificate, the second certificate in the chain, I suppose, the certificate that is unique for each device, has a serial number. See [here](https://gist.github.com/thestinger/27e38cb7939c35cd03d9fff4ac022775#file-1_device_intermediate-txt-L7), same for my samsung devices.
I could not find any proof that this certificate and serial number is indeed unique for each device, or is it just a coincidence that on my devices that was the case.

So I want to ask here, is it true that the second certificate is unique for each device and can it be used to uniquely identify a device?

Unlike Android ID, that is unique for each application since Android 8 (API level 26), this serial number would be the same for all apps in the system, which makes it suitable for identification of the device without READ_PHONE_STATE permission.

Comment: If the certificate that may be is device unique are part of a certificate chain then device specific certificate would have to be generated while manufacturing the device because later this can not be done without the private key of the used CA certificate (which is not present on the device for sure). The effort for deploying device unique certificates in production in a secure way requires a lot of effort, I am not sure if this is done for every Android device. Thus I would assume certs are model specific not device specific.

Comment: You need two phones with the same hardware and Android version + patch level and then  compare their certificates if they are device unique or not.